# semantic ui react __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I'm using React Boilerplate version 3.4.0 and when importing components from semantic-ui-react I get the following error:

```
Dynamic page loading failed TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function
    at new Button (Button.js:83)
    at eval (ReactCompositeComponent.js:295)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (ReactCompositeComponent.js:294)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:280)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:188)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:46)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:238)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:691)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:516)
```

I'm importing the button component using

```
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
```

but what surprises me the most is that, for some components, the import works:

```
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'
```

works.

Also, when I log the component outside of the render function:

```
console.log(<Button></Button>)
```

I get relevant log:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: null, ref: null,
props: {…}, …}
```

Comment: try to reinstall semantic-ui-react package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so problem solved (searched one night and 10 minutes after posting on StackOverflow I find the solution :p)

I was using semantic ui react with a version compatible to react 16 and not react 15 which I was using.

I then downgraded semantic-ui-react to version 0.81.3 using

```
yarn add semantic-ui-react@0.81.3
```